# how to remove values ​from a column based on the specific name within the group?

Tags: r

I would like to remove values (<11) in column y based on group name "genetic" within column B.

For example below:

```
dfa
ID     B          Y
1    genetic      10
2    life         20
3    life         10
4    genetic      10
5    life         20
6    genetic      50
7    life         25
8    life         45
9    genetic      60
10   genetic      70
```

output

```
dfa
ID     B         y
1    genetic     10
2    life        20
3    life        10 
4    genetic     10
5    life        20
6    life        25
7    life        45
```

Please notice that values lower than 11 were removed from dataset in the output.
I would like create this conditional to deal it.
Does someone could help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `dplyr::filter()` for this:

```
dfa %>% 
  dplyr::filter(!(Y < 11 & B == 'genetic'))
```